# How to expand background from flexbox grid text & images with equal height

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, flexbox, centering

I have done a flexbox grid, it combines text cells with image cells. All the cells have the same height in each resolution, also text cells. Text cells have the text centered vertically, and this is a must. Now I need to assign each text cell a different background-color, but here I have the problem.

With *align-items: center* the text is centered vertically, but the background color is only applied to the text. Without *align-items: center* the background expands to all the cell, but the content is not centered vertically.
Here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/nuriarai/pen/yNKOxO)

Any suggestions in how to achieve the two features at same time?

- vertically centered text
- different background-color for each text cell

Thanks!

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
    box-sizing:         border-box;
}
body { 
  margin: 0; 
  background: #333; 
  padding: 30px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
h2  {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.wrap-items { 
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap; 
  flex-flow: row wrap; 
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}
.wrap-items .item { 
  -webkit-box-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 1 0 33.333%; 
  width: 33.33333%; 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: steelblue;
}
.wrap-items .item.span-2 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 2 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 2 0 auto;
  flex: 2 0 auto; 
  width: 66.6666%; 
  height: auto;
}
.wrap-items .item img { 
  width: 100%; 
  height: auto;
}
.wrap-items .item > .text {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}
.item.un .text{
  background-color: orange;
}
.item.dos {
  background-color: brown;
}
.item.tres {
  background-color: violet;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  .wrap-items .item { 
    margin: 0;
  flex: 50%
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .wrap-items .item { 
    margin: 0;
    flex: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Codepen link is broken - try http://codepen.io/nuriarai/pen/yNKOxO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *transforms* instead of *flexbox* to vertically center the text.

1) Remove `align-items: center` from the `.wrap-items` class

2) Adjust the `.wrap-items .item > .text` class like this:

```
.wrap-items .item > .text {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

### [Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/oXqqRr)

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #333;
  padding: 30px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.wrap-items {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  //align-items: center;
  //align-content: center;

}
.wrap-items .item {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 1 0 33.333%;
  width: 33.33333%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: steelblue;
  position: relative;
}
.wrap-items .item.span-2 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 2 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 2 0 auto;
  flex: 2 0 auto;
  width: 66.6666%;
  height: auto;
}
.wrap-items .item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.wrap-items .item > .text {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
.item.un {
  background-color: orange;
}
.item.dos {
  background-color: brown;
}
.item.tres {
  background-color: purple;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  .wrap-items .item {
    margin: 0;
    flex: 50%
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .wrap-items .item {
    margin: 0;
    flex: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-items">
  <!-- row 1 -->
  <div class="item span-2">
    <div class="text">
      <h2>THE TITLE</h2>
      <p>Just be water my friend</p>
      <p>Small people can do very big things.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/800/600" alt>
  </div>
  <!-- row 2 -->
  <div class="item un">
    <div class="text ">
      <a href="">one or more lines of text inside the box</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/800/600" alt>
  </div>
  <div class="item dos">
    <div class="text">
      <a href="">text in the middle</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- row 3 -->
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/800/600" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item tres">
    <div class="text">
      <a href="">three lines of text centered vertically in the middle of the box</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/800/600" alt>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Danield, it seems a good solution! but it has a problem when we reduce max-width to less than 400px for small devices  and putting flex to 100%, the text is placed besides the image, and text cell is totally hidden. I added this snipet to the code: `@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .wrap-items .item { 
    margin: 0;
    flex: 100%;
  }
  .wrap-items .item > .text {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: inherit;
    transform: none;
  }
}` but the height is not maintained then.

Comment: I realise that this happens also with my original code, so it seems another problem.  Therefore, I accept your answer.